# Display results from mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop an upcoming course dates for my website. I want to maintain the data in an mysql database. I have set up 3 table in msql.

1.courses

2.category

3.coursedates

All are linked by course_id.

Basically I want to present the data from coursedates in the following way in PHP using a query.

Course Title                  No Of Days                    Course Date

I have tried using the follwoing coding

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mentertraining");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "SELECT `coursedates`.`coursedate_id`,`courses`.`course_title`,`courses`.`no_of_days`,`category`.`category_name`,`coursedates`.`date1` FROM coursedates\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN `mentertraining`.`courses` ON `coursedates`.`course_id` = `courses`.`course_id` \n"
    . "LEFT JOIN `mentertraining`.`category` ON `courses`.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Course Title</th>
<th>Course Date</th>

</tr>";

while($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date1'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: ...and what happened?

Comment: I get this error when I use the above code. Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mentertraining\pp.php on line 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with the following :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mentertraining");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "SELECT `coursedates`.`coursedate_id`,`courses`.`course_title`,`courses`.`no_of_days`,`category`.`category_name`,`coursedates`.`date1` FROM coursedates "
    . " LEFT JOIN `mentertraining`.`courses` ON `coursedates`.`course_id` = `courses`.`course_id` "
    . " LEFT JOIN `mentertraining`.`category` ON `courses`.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Course Title</th><th>Course Date</th></tr>";

while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['course_title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date1'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. just run it and still getting these 2 errors. Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mentertraining\trial.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mentertraining\trial.php on line 17

Comment: try again and using `mysqli_query($con,$query);`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing mysql_* and mysqli:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mentertraining");
```

But:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);//?
```

Use mysqli_query instead:

```
$query = "SELECT 
       `coursedates`.`coursedate_id`,
       `courses`.`course_title`,
       `courses`.`no_of_days`,
       `category`.`category_name`,
       `coursedates`.`date1` 
FROM
    coursedates
LEFT JOIN
      `mentertraining`.`courses` 
ON 
   `coursedates`.`course_id` = `courses`.`course_id`
LEFT JOIN
     `mentertraining`.`category` 
ON 
   `courses`.`category_id` = `category`.`category_id`
LIMIT 0, 30";

$result = mysqli_query($query);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Course Title</th>
<th>Course Date</th>

</tr>";

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['course_title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date1'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: And `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Sorry guys bit of a newbie. Ive just changed the mysql to mysqli but still getting these errors. 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mentertraining\pp.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mentertraining\pp.php on line 22

Comment: Hi user4035. That as sorted out the first error still getting this one though Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mentertraining\trial.php on line 17

Comment: @user2536134 It means, that your SQL query is incorrect and mysqli_query returns false

Comment: @user2536134 I updated my answer, so all the query is displayed on the screen, but there is no difference with your query. Check it carefully in mysql console. I can't tell you what's wrong with it without seeing the sample data and tables structures.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your query might be more legible rewritten something like this...

```
"
SELECT cd.coursedate_id
     , c.course_title
     , c.no_of_days
     , t.category_name
     , cd.date1 
  FROM coursedates cd
  LEFT 
  JOIN courses c
    ON c.course_id = cd.course_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN category t
    ON t.category_id = c.category_id 
 LIMIT 0, 30;
 "
```

Incidentally, it seems odd that you could have course dates for a course that didn't exist, so that first OUTER JOIN could probably be rewritten as an INNER JOIN!